# Can the raspberry pi be used as a serial converter to debug other boards?

Tags: uart, serial-console

I have a board running linux and it doesn't boot when connecting a specific hardware, the board doesn't even load the kernel so i have to use a serial cable to see what's causing the issue, currently i don't have a serial to usb converter so i would like to know if i can use the raspberry pi instead, i've used an arduino board as converter before and was wondering if this is possible with a raspberry pi basically i would like to connect Tx and Rx to the board and use a program like minicom inside the raspberry 
to watch the boot sequence.

**UPDATE:** I'm using raspberry pi 3 model B running raspbian jessie

**uname -a** : `Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50-v7+ #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: No problem provided 1) the other system uses 3V3 TTL on its TX line, 2) you set the correct baud rate on the Pi, and 3) the other system is configured to output on TX during boot.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no - this is possible but not simple. The hardware UART on the Pi is usually used as a boot console (to help in debugging random crashes during boot, etc.) In order to use to UART as a general purpose device, you need to disable this.

If you want to change the console UART, you need to edit (as root) `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Then delete `console=ttyAMA0,115200` and  `kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200`

Also edit `/etc/inittab` and comment out the line like `T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100`

Bear in mind that the I/O is 3.3v, so it will be fine for connecting directly to another mcu, but not to a RS232 port.

More details [here](http://raspberrypihobbyist.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/raspberry-pi-serial-port.html)

Comment: `cmdline.txt` doesn't have `console=ttyAMA0,115200` but it has `console=serial0,115200` which i deleted, also since raspbian no longer uses `inittab` i used systemctl to disable serial service but found that it was already disabled, after reboot tried to use minicom with ttyAMA0 but couldn't get any data, tried to short the TX and Rx but i'm not getting loop back either